# Bootstrap. One column as high as two columns on top of each other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do something like this:

```
|                  |           |
|        1         |           |
|                  |           |
|__________________|      3    |
|                  |           |
|                  |           |
|        2         |           |
|                  |           |
```

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class-"col-md-9 col-lg-9">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class-"col-md-9 col-lg-9">
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="visible-md visible-lg col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <img class="highImage" src="assets/img/surfboard2.jpeg" alt="...">
</div>
</div>
```

But I cannot figure out how to do it with bootstrap.js rows and colums. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div>
            top row
        </div>
        <div>
            bottom row
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        right cell
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Figured it out when i posted my code. Mixed up rows and colums there for a second.